# Display php data in a html table using while loop

Tags: php, html

Each time i echo out information from the database using while loop, the first results are displayed in only one row while the rest of the results are printed outside the table as raw text.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
        <tr class="bg-info">
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Order</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Paid</th>
        <th>Created Time</th>
        <th>Updated Time</th>
        <th>Update Order</th>
        <th>Delete Order</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
       <?php
        if($sql->num_rows > 0){
       while($data = $sql->fetch_array()):
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $database->escape_value($data['custom_id']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $database->escape_value($data['order_id']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $database->escape_value($data['title']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $database->escape_value($data['quantity']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $database->escape_value($data['total']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $database->escape_value($data['paid']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $database->escape_value($data['created_at']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $database->escape_value($data['updated_at']); ?></td>
        <td><a href="update_order.php?id=<?php echo $database->escape_value($data['id']); ?>">Update Order</a></td>
        <td><a href="delete_order.php?id=<?php echo $database->escape_value($data['id']); ?>" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this order?'); ">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php endwhile; }else 
    echo "<div class='btn bg-danger'>search not found</div>";
?>
```

Guys,only the first result is displayed proparly in the table, i want all the data display inside the table.

Comment: Looks like a typo.  You're closing the `</tbody>` and `</table>` inside the loop.  If you don't want to close those in the loop, move them out of the loop.  (Hint: When you write code that outputs HTML and it doesn't look right in the browser, the ***very first thing*** you should do is open View Source in the browser and *look* at the HTML to see if it's what you expected.)

Comment: @David Thank you so much.

Comment: Don't know what `$database->escape_value()` is, but it looks like escaping for database queries and not for html. Use `htmlspecialchars()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the table inside the loop. It's important that you keep the row only in the while.

Then be careful to close all brackets correctly.

```
<thead>
        <tr class="bg-info">
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Order</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Paid</th>
        <th>Created Time</th>
        <th>Updated Time</th>
        <th>Update Order</th>
        <th>Delete Order</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
       <?php
        if($sql->num_rows > 0){
            while($data = $sql->fetch_array()){
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $database->escape_value($data['custom_id']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $database->escape_value($data['order_id']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $database->escape_value($data['title']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $database->escape_value($data['quantity']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $database->escape_value($data['total']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $database->escape_value($data['paid']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $database->escape_value($data['created_at']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $database->escape_value($data['updated_at']); ?></td>
        <td><a href="update_order.php?id=<?php echo $database->escape_value($data['id']); ?>">Update Order</a></td>
        <td><a href="delete_order.php?id=<?php echo $database->escape_value($data['id']); ?>" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this order?'); ">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php 
if($sql->num_rows == 0){    
    echo "<div class='btn bg-danger'>search not found</div>";
}
?>
```